# I have a simple JQuery popup - works fine with Chrome and Firefox but nothing shows with IE9

Tags: jquery

I'm just a beginner and I hope somebody can immediately see why IE9 does nothing with my Jquery popup (Chrome and Firefox work fine)..................
And here is a bit of the html which calls the popup.....

```
<!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
  <div id="pop-up">
      <div id="leave_popup">
           here is my popup content (the css for #pop-up sets the div
           display to 'none')........
      </div>
  </div>
```

And here is my Jquery popup...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#req_13").hover(function(e) {$("#pop-up").show();
 });
 $("#req_13").mousemove(function(e) {
     var moveLeft = 20;
     var moveDown = 10;
     $("#pop-up").css('top',+(e.pageY) + moveDown).css('left',+ (e.pageX) + moveLeft);
 });
 $("#leave_popup").mouseleave(function(){
     $("#pop-up").hide();
 });
```

Comment: You had an extra `});` at the end of your code - removed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

IE breaks at the slightest code imperfections.  You have extra `+` symbols in your `.css` method.  Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#req_13").hover(function(e) {
      $("#pop-up").show();
 });

$("#req_13").mousemove(function(e) {
   var moveLeft = 20;
   var moveDown = 10;
  $("#pop-up").css('top',e.pageY + moveDown).css('left',e.pageX + moveLeft);
 });

$("#leave_popup").mouseleave(function(){
   $("#pop-up").hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to do with your use of pageY and pageX.

Off the top of my head in quirks mode there is a script that is something like:

```
if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
    posx = e.pageX;
    posy = e.pageY;
} else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
    posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#req_13").hover(function(e) {
        $("#pop-up").show();
    });

    $("#req_13").mousemove(function(e) {
        var moveLeft = 20;
        var moveDown = 10;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posX = e.pageX;
            posY = e.pageY;
        } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
            posX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        var newLeft = posX + moveLeft;
        var newTop = posY + moveDown;
        $("#pop-up").css({'left': newLeft, 'top': newTop});
    });

    $("#leave_popup").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#pop-up").hide();
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/wBaHe/5/